# Using `sed` without piping multiple times

Tags: sed

Example:

```
echo one two three | sed 's/ /\n/g' | sed 's/^/:/g'
```

output:

> :one
>   :two
>   :three

Without piping:

```
echo one two three | sed 's/ /\n/g;s/^/:/g'
```

output:

> :one
>   two
>   three

seems like first pattern isn't expanded before executing second one, but I really don't know much about sed

How can I use first example without piping twice?

PS Pattern used in examples is informative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem here is that sed decides on what constitutes a line (a pattern that it works on) before executing any commands. That is, if you have only one pattern (`one two three`), it won't get reinterpreted as multiple lines after execution of `s/ /\n/g`. If would be still a single pattern, although that would be the one that contains newlines inside it.

The simplest workaround to make sed reinterpret patterns along the newly inserted newlines is just running sed twice, as you did.

Another workaround would be adding something like `m` option (multi-line buffer) to `s` command:

```
$ echo one two three | sed 's/ /\n/g;s/^/:/mg'
:one
:two
:three
```

Answer (score 11):

The other way to do it is with repeated `-e` options:

```
echo one two three | sed -e 's/ /\n:/g' -e 's/^/:/g'
```

This is easier to understand when you have many operations to do; you can align the separate operations on separate lines:

```
echo one two three |
sed -e 's/ /\n:/g' \
    -e 's/^/:/g'
```

For example, I have a script to generate outline documents from templates.  One part of the script contains:

```
sed -e "s/[:]YEAR:/$(date +%Y)/g" \
    -e "s/[:]TODAY:/$today/" \
    -e "s/[:]BASE:/$BASE/g" \
    -e "s/[:]base:/$base/g" \
    -e "s/[:]FILE:/$FILE/g" \
    -e "s/[:]file:/$file/g" \
    $skeleton |
...
```

Although it could be done on one line, it would not promote readability.

Answer (score 2):

You could put all that into one regular expression like this:

```
echo one two three | sed 's/\([^ ]\+\)\( \+\|$\)/:\1\n/g'
```

The first part `\([^ ]\+\)` selects your words (i.e. a string of characters which is not a space. The seconds part `\( \+\|$\)` matches either one or more spaces or the line end (which is required for the `three` which has no space after it.

Then we we just build the line by using a back-reference to the word matched in part 1.

Comment: And yes, the escapes on most of the metacharacters make this thing rather unreadable but actually it's rather simple.

Comment: This inserts an extra newline `\n` after the `three`. N.B. sed appends a newline to the whatever is in the pattern space before printing.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
echo one two three | sed 'y/ /\n/;s/^/:/mg'
:one
:two
:three
```